# Is it possible to call 2nd parent class method by using child class object reference inside python in case of inheritance? If yes then how?

Tags: python, inheritance

Suppose we have two class with different names but with the same name method in both class with no arguments.

For example:

```
class Parent_1: # define parent class
    def myMethod(self):
        print 'Calling parent method_1'
```

Another is:

```
class Parent_2: # define parent class
    def myMethod(self):
        print 'Calling parent method_2'
```

I have another class (child class) which inherit these both classes.

```
class Child(Parent_1, Parent_2): # define child class
    print "abc"
    #Parent_1().myMethod();
    #Parent_2().myMethod();
```

See here, if I try to call 2nd class method then I can call with the 2nd parent class reference inside child class.
But when I am trying to call from outside by using child class object reference.

```
c = Child()
c.myMethod()
```

Output is:

```
abc
Calling parent method_1
```

Here, you can watch it will call 1st parent class method by default using child class reference.

What if I want to call same method of another class using child class reference explicitly without changing inherited base classes order?

Is it possible or not ? If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the unbound function and pass the `self` parameter explicitly:

```
Parent_2.myMethod(c)
```

Comment: In this scenario what approach i can assume @Rawing ?

Comment: @InfinityRazor This is just a way to call a method, Top-down or Bottom-up has nothing to do with it. But OOP is generally considered Bottom-up.

Comment: Well, this technique is really helpful thanks for valuable answer @Rawing.